# Upload multiple images laravel in single row table

Tags: database, laravel, image, upload

I'm trying to upload multiple images to my database and then show it on another page, but when I upload them, I can see only one image and not the rest.
This is my html

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputGroupFile01">Upload foto's</label>
<input type="file" name="image" class="form-control-file" id="inputGroupFile01" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01" multiple>
</div>
```

and this is my controller to save it

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
            $request->file('image')->move('storage/images', $fileNameToStore);

        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }
```

And this is my code to show it

```
<a download="retourmelding_{{$retour->firmaname}}" href="{{ asset('storage/images/'.$retour->images) }}" title="Foto">
<img alt="Foto" src="{{ asset('storage/images/'.$retour->images) }}"></a>
```

So uploading works perfectly, I also made my input multiple, and when I choose images only the first image is uploaded to my database, and that is the only picture I can see.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form tag

```
<form method="post" action="YOUR URL GOES HERE" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{csrf_field()}}
//...
</form>
```

> 2) The name of your file input must be `image[]`

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" class="form-control-file" id="inputGroupFile01" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01" multiple>
```

> 3) Backend Validation

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'image' => 'required',
    'image.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
]);
```

> 4) Insert multiple images in the database

```
//...
if($request->hasfile('image'))
         {

            foreach($request->file('image') as $image)
            {
                $name=$image->getClientOriginalName();
                $image->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);  
                $data[] = $name;  
            }
         }

         $myModel = new App\MyModel();
         $myModel->filename = json_encode($data);


        $myModel->save();
//...
```